# Как выполнять параметр поиска по условию? typeorm (queryBuilder)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, querybuilder

Есть запрос на получение данных из БД постгрес:

```
const uni = await this.contactInfoRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('contact_info')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.university', 'university')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.country', 'country')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.region', 'region')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.city', 'city')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.directions', 'directions')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('directions.admissionInfo', 'admissionInfo')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('directions.info', 'info')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.prices', 'prices')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.structureUniversity', 'structureUniversity')
  .orderBy(`university.${field}`, `${type}`)
  .where('university.status = true')
  .where("country.id = :id", { id: country }) //1
  .where("region.id = :id", { id: region }) //23
  .where("city.id = :id", { id: city }) //38
  .skip(skip)
  .take(take)
  .getMany()
```

При указании country/region/city все работает, но если хоть 1 параметр передать как 0 или null запрос ничего не выводит, в то время как аналогичный запрос но на .find отлично работает, в чем дело? как сделать region и city не обязательными!!!!

Аналогичный пример с .find (рабочий)

```
 const total = await this.contactInfoRepo.find({
    relations: [...],
    where: {
       country: {
          id: country
       },
       region: {
          id: region
       },
       city: {
          id: city
       },
       university: {
          status: true
       },
    },
 })
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Выборка по нескольким параметрам typeorm/nestjs (createQueryBuilder)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485729/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-typeorm-nestjs-createquerybuilder)

Comment: Это не дубликат, тут другой вопрос по этому отрывку кода, мне необходимо обработать отсутствие id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
const qb = this.contactInfoRepo.createQueryBuilder('contact_info');

qb.where('university.status = true')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.university', 'university')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.country', 'country')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.region', 'region')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('contact_info.city', 'city')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.directions', 'directions')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('directions.admissionInfo', 'admissionInfo')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('directions.info', 'info')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.prices', 'prices')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('university.structureUniversity', 'structureUniversity');


if (country) {
  qb.andWhere("country.id = :country_id", { country_id: country });
}
if (region) {
  qb.andWhere("region.id = :region_id", { region_id: region });
}
if (city) {
  qb.andWhere("city.id = :city_id", { city_id: city });
}
if (type) {
  qb.orderBy(`university.${field}`, `${type}`);
}

const uni = await qb.skip(skip).take(take).getMany();
```

Comment: спасибо, все получилось)